# Is ROS compatible with all robots?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to know if ROS can work with all kits? or needs specific requirements? I mean, can I buy any kit and control it by ROS? If yes, is there any needed chip, ports, or connectors? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202373/is-ros-compatible-with-all-robots?/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the abstract, ROS could be compatible with any robot which has a computer interface. However, to be compatible, there needs to be a program (or piece of hardware) which sits between ROS and the robot hardware to translate ROS messages/services, etc into commands that the robot hardware can understand, and vice versa. This is generally called a driver - it subscribes to and advertises ROS topics, and communicates with the robot over USB, serial, EtherCAT, etc.

Many robots already have ROS support. An extensive, though incomplete, list can be found on the [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4